# Question on Decile Analysis - Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, mathematical-statistics

I was doing a comparative research on Decile Analysis vs Confusion Matrix and came across the this link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blorr/vignettes/introduction.html

When Binomial Logistic regression algorithm is run, generally people tend to take the probability cut off as 0.5 and based on that confusion matrix is created and all measures like
specificity, sensitivity, accuracy are calculated.

If decile analysis is done on the dataset after running Logistic regression, the probabilities generated are arranged in descending order.

Under "Gains Table & Lift Chart" topic in the link above, deciles are created on the dataset and accuracy, sensitivity and specificity are computed for each decile.

My question is why does the accuracy keeps decreasing as we move from Decile 1 to Decile 10. Mathematically, (TN + TP) keeps going down so the accuracy falls. But from the algorithm point of view, shouldn't the algorithm do a good job of classifying correctly in each Decile?

Also, how different (good or bad) Decile Analysis analysis is as compared to Confusion Matrix?

Comment: That vignette is really terrible.  I wouldn't use that package or their advice.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, Thanks for the suggestion. What's your general advice on Decile Analysis vs Confusion Matrix?

Comment: They are different.  The deciles aren't deciles of predicted probabilities, but of something else (I think variable importance).